# how to integrate login with linked in in chrome extension

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Does any one know how to integrate linked In Login method with chrome extension?

I am trying to integrate Login in with linked in my chrome extension but have no idea how to do it. i tried this code but it says:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").result(ShowProfileData);
    }

    function ShowProfileData(profiles) {
        var member = profiles.values[0];
        var id=member.id;
    }
</script>

<script type="in/Login"></script>
```

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: you need to mention where that html is. background? content? injected?

Comment: @ZigMandel it is separate html file injected as:
"web_accessible_resources": [ "oauth.html" ]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have likely spelled the resource incorrectly. I just ran into the same issue because I was trying to call the file oauth.js but in my directory I had spelled it ouath.js. Double check all your spelling and the paths that you are using to find files.